# word processor in c# or c++

Tags: c#, c++

I learned C Sharp for one purpose, to write a word processor that includes my needs. For example that you could play with the spaces between words, and the spaces between the lines, raise one word higher from the row, and many other similar things.
When I start working on it in c# - winForms I see the possibilities are very limited, Indeed there are ways to do almost everything With effort, but my question is if I on the right way, maybe c# is not the language to it, maybe I should work with c++.
What do you think?

Comment: It's going to take effort no matter what language you use, what specific limitations do you speak of?

Comment: Anything you think would be difficult in C# is going to be at least 3 times more difficult in C++. And as a beginner this is not exactly the kind of application you would want to tackle in C++ first thing. Writing an advanced word processor is going to be hard. Buckle down and start learning. This is a marathon, not a sprint.

Comment: I would start by looking at what other people have done, either to modify their code or at least use it as a learning tool: http://csharpopensource.com/editors.aspx

Comment: What do you mean when you say "play with spaces between words", "between lines"? Because if I'm interpreting it right then there are several applications available that have this functionality. So I think you shouldn't be writing this yourself at all.

Comment: Microsoft Word & Word Pefect does everything you describe.  You don't want to know what I think.  If you have to ask any questions surrounding how to do this then your not qualified to do it.

Comment: onoots - Regarding your question, for example, if the text is formatted in two columns, and they are not equal in length, one column for example has 10 rows, and column two has 11 rows, then increase the spacing between words, and then I have 11 lines in each column. Also if you have two columns per page, and each column has a few paragraphs, and two columns are not equal in length, you can play with the spacing between paragraphs, so that both columns are equal in length.

Comment: Ramhiund - Regarding your question, I work very well with "Word", but there are things that can not be done in "Word", and for that I want to write a word processor.

Comment: As others stated you will find writing a word processor quite difficult. Text itself is an extremely complex task. If you do not understand this http://xkcd.com/1015/ you should do some additional research.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote my own text editor for unformatted, monospaced text, which is much easier than writing one for formatted text as you have in mind. It is made up of 250 c# source files with a total of 800 Kbytes code. Only to give you an idea.

You will not be able to use existing controls and will have to write your own control for text display and manipulation, unless you use a RTF editor control; however, in that case you could use an existing RTF editor as well.

[image]

If you want to learn c# then choose an easier task, like writing a simple notepad editor for monospaced fonts without any chichi. You can then consider adding support for proportional fonts and go gradually towards an increasingly more complicated editor.

Comment: RTF stands for Rich Text Format, a file format developed by Microsoft, which allows storing formatted texts. There are several RTF editor controls available for WinForms, WPF and WebForms from Microsoft or third parties. E.g. `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox`.

Comment: `Wordpad`, delivered with the Windows operating system (as part of the Accessories) is a RTF editor. MS-Word can read from and write to RTF-Files.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is much more difficult than you think. Rendering text properly is an incredibly complex problem. Whatever the programming language, "GUI" programming is a bad choice. Work with HTML (generate it and use one of the many possibilities to render it).

Comment: What do you mean, I will write software as inDesign or Microsoft Word in HTML ?